# Any VCARD generator class for Zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, vcf-vcard

Hi guys I need a class to generate vcards - something that I can use with the Zend Framework - nothing too flashy. Thanks again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is vcardphp on sourceforge.net (for php in general), should'nt be hard to make into a Zend module.

And also http://www.bitfolge.de/index.php?l=en&s=phpvcard.

I have used both for various projects.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new proposal for a Zend_Vcard component.

The current code lives here:

http://code.google.com/p/zendvcard/